# Outdoor kitchen worktop options

Tags: kitchen-counters

I'm preparing to build a semi outdoor kitchen. It will be exposed to the elements (I'm in Thailand) but under a roof top. Frame will likely be built using metal drywall studs, with cement board covering top and sides and possibly a wooden frame in front of that to hang doors off.

I've been looking around online for worktop options. The go to seems to be tiles. But to me, having tiles as a worktop seems odd. I feel a worktop should have a continuous smooth surface.

I'm not comfortable building a concrete countertop, slabs of stone willl be too expensive, and wood seems a bad idea given the humidity and temperatures here.

What other options are there for me?

Answer (score 0):

Stainless steel! For my home I custom made a one piece stainless counter and backsplash that goes up the wall all the way to the upper cabinets. It's impervious to just about anything and looks amazing! The only downside is that it is a pain to keep clean.

Answer (score 0):

If you are into chasing the latest design trends then go for the Shou Sugi Ban wood. It is durable, lasts long, doesn't require maintenance, and so on.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I've removed the possibly-spamming link from your answer. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.